# Download and convert YouTube videos to MP3 and organise into channels/playlists

Tags: video, download, mp3, youtube, download-manager

I'd like to download YouTube videos by specifying a YouTube channel URL or playlist URL. I then want to convert the videos to MP3 and put them in a separate folder according to the playlist.

Is this possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Is there anything you've already tried? What is your operating system?

Comment: Yes, I've tried wondershare, http://www.download-you-tube.com/youtube-downloader, but it doesn't suit my requirements. I have windows 8 pro 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

With [`youtube-dl`](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), you can download an entire playlist and extract the audio of videos to MP3 or AAC (`.m4a`). It requires [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) to be installed on your system.

This is a script you can run in Bash, assuming you have `ffmpeg` and `youtube-dl` installed.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <playlist-url>"
  exit 1
fi

playlist="$1"
title="$(youtube-dl -s "$playlist" | perl -ne 'if (/(?<=Downloading playlist: )(.*)/) { print $1 }')"
mkdir -p "$title"
cd "$title"
youtube-dl -x "$playlist"
cd ..
```

Save it, e.g. under `download.sh`, and make it executable with `chmod +x download.sh`. Then, run it like so:

```
./download.sh http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLs4hTtftqnlCxP-7nkw3iNep08rvg79YB
```

It'll leave you with just the audio files in a folder named like the playlist.

Comment: THANK YOUUU soo much, your solution worked like a lovely charm, only one thing (excuse my greed), I'm trying to download videos from a whole channel not just a playlist, is that possible ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, at least not with `youtube-dl`, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

#### Download

I don't think there is a piece of software out there that will do all that for you, but I have a alternate way of doing it.

Using Firefox, download this free add-on: [Download Flash and Video :: Add-ons for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/download-flash-and-video/)

This is a plugin that will allow your browser to detect any Flash video being played and download it with a simple click.

#### Converting

[Xilisoft](http://www.xilisoft.com/video-converter.html) is one of the best video converters I've ever used so far. You can pretty much convert anything to anything (format to format).

As far as the rest of the question goes, I'm sure you can figure it out. :)

Comment: Would be nice to explain how to download each video from a playlist without having to click through it – imagine there's a playlist with 40 videos.

Comment: @slhck, thanks for the edit, but honestly i have no idea what hes talking about with playlists. My answer will do most of the heavy lifting, as far as his playlist goes, i think hes looking for a magic program to do ALL of that for him with a click of a button, which doesn't exist, hes going have make his own play lists.

Comment: The OP means YouTube playlists, which collect a number of videos: http://www.youtube.com/yt/playbook/playlists.html

Comment: Never seen one, nope. Why slhck, have you? if so.. where?

Comment: Could be that you don't use YouTube frequently, but they're used quite often, especially for music videos or series. I'm sure you'll stumble across a few ones if you browse YouTube for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the program [`youtube-dl`](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), which runs on Windows, Linux and OS X.

[This tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1040) is for Linux mint. Here's [a tutorial for other Linuxes or OS X](http://kroliki.in.ua/?p=372).

Then, you can use the program ffmpeg and convert the downloaded file to MP3.

Comment: youtube-dl is not only fairly universal in the repositories of linux distros (at least, the ones aimed at people who are likely to want to download youtube videos), but it can work perfectly well on Windows, at least [according to the youtube-dl website](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/).

Comment: Can you please describe how ImageMagick can convert videos to MP3? I'd be very surprised if it had such capabilities.

Comment: I wrote imagemagick instead of ffmpeg. Sorry, was tired - which is an bad exuse. slhck, you did the right thing to edit my text and questioning me about my statement regarding imagemagick.

Comment: No problem. I was sure you meant something else :) By the way, I later found out that `youtube-dl` could extract audio right away, as long as `ffmpeg` is installed. See the `-x` option. (Oh, and please note that you have to ping users with @slhck in order to have them receive a reply!)